# How to unmarshal array or list using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an XML file and I need to set it up with my POJO class

```
<ids xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" >
  <a:string>100</a:string>
  <a:string>101</a:string>
  <a:string>102</a:string>
  ... etc..
</ids>
```

Which annotation do I have to use, to fetch these values

I am using the following way.

```
@XmlElement(name="string",namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
    protected List<String> id;
```

but I am getting null

Comment: Is that the whole XML so root element is `<ids>`?

Answer (score 1):

You did not present the class containing `protected List<String> id`. It should be something like

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ids")
public class Wrapper {
    @XmlElement(name = "string",
                namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
    protected List<String> id;
}
```

to have the list populated. Also you can name the class `Ids` and remove `name = 'Ids'`.